# Share an interface between two apps?

Tags: interface, typescript

What mechanism for sharing can I put in place to allow two separate typescript projects to communicate along common interfaces?

The basic idea is that I have one main project that will implement the interfaces, and there will be another project that consumes them.  However I don't want either of the projects to be dependent on the other.

Specifically: How can I can create and distribute a library of contracts (and perhaps any functionality that complements them if applicable).
Are there any established or emerging conventions in the TypeScript ecosystem to distribute libraries of interfaces via NPM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several years and many projects later, the simplest answer to this question today is to simply publish a `.d.ts` to an npm package and consume it!  This project can be built from typescript sources and even include built code.

Of course, a lot of this answer now is long after TypeScript and the JS community have matured and come together to establish these conventions.

Answer (score 4):

Just define the interface in a separate file, or collect all shared interfaces in a file `interfaces.ts` (or a `interfaces.d.ts`). Both projects can reference this file, you can have copies of that file in both projects.

TypeScript is not like i.e. C# where you have to reference an underlying assembly (although this will be fixed in C# with [assembly neutral interfaces](http://davidfowl.com/assembly-neutral-interfaces/)).

But beware: TypeScript has no dedicated runtime that assures your interfaces match. As everything is still JavaScript, at runtime you have to make sure the interfaces match. If one projects uses i.e. another version of the interfaces with properties that didn't exist in previous versions, you will still run into trouble.

Comment: Have any practices emerged for distributing interfaces via NPM?

Comment: Yes, but not via npm but the tsd tool that uses the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) repo. But you should only add your interfaces if the library implementing them is available to others, not for your internal use. For internal use, you might setup a custom repo and can still use the tsd tool if you point it to that repo.

Comment: Also note that the tsc compiler can create the .d.ts file of your library (which will also contain the type annotation of exported classes) for you.

Comment: Even with this solution it seems as though you would be maintaining two seperate files. The ideal solution is to just manage one that's in a central location and have your projects import it. The only reasonable solution I've found thus far is build out your interfaces in their own projects and keep them in NPM or some other repo where you can reference the interface project/modules via npm install. This way, the only drawback is having to go and update all your projects anytime you have an update.

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any established or emerging conventions in the TypeScript ecosystem to distribute libraries of interfaces via NPM

Use the `typescript` key in your package.json to point to the definition file :

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd#link-to-bundled-definitions